# Get the history of your instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a ubuntu EC2 aws instance. I recently deleted a volume from my EC2. I created it using a public snapshot. The problem is that i forgot to  format the volume before deleting it. 
Now i don't remember the id of that volume and my data is somewhere public. Is there any way to see the past history of all the volume or any way that i could again find that particular volume just to attach it and format it again? Any way to see all the volume that has been attached to an instance?
I also want to ask something about public snapshots. Do they contain data? Should one first format the snapshot and use it or without format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if your concerns are unfounded, based on a misunderstanding of how EBS works.

When you create a volume from a public snapshot, your volume is initialized with a *copy* of the snapshot.  This is a one-way process.  When you modify the contents, only your copy of the data changes -- not what's in the public snapshot.  When you delete the volume, your data is destroyed.

Yes, public snapshots contain "data," otherwise they'd be empty.  You wouldn't want to format them, first, because that would defeat the purpose of using whatever snapshot you used.  If you want a volume that's empty, you would create an empty volume.

Comment: Thank you for easing my mind on that query! But i do wanna ask another question..what's the difference if u create a empty volume without giving a snapshot id or if you use a snapshot id?